# java- How to check whether scheduler is working

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am running a scheduled task in the web application using the java SingleThreadScheduledExecutor

The problem I have is - **How do I identify whether the scheduler is still running and has not crashed?**

Is there a better way of doing it rather than having another scheduler to check this particular scheduler

Comment: Your scheduled task should be doing some task? checking whether that task is done or not may be an option?

Comment: Add log in your task and check the result of log.

Comment: Hi all thanks for the response .The scheduler does the particular task every 30 seconds. What I require is a way to check whether the scheduler is running and if not start it. This should be done automatically

Answer (score 2):

there is actually a way to check

```java
public class TaskSchedulerService{
    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler; //initialize it here or in constructor 
    private Map<String,ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduleMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public TaskSchedulerServiceImpl() {
        this.schedulerName = schedulerName;
        taskScheduler.initialize();
    }

    public boolean isScheduled(String taskId) {
        final ScheduledFuture<?> exits = scheduledTasks.get(taskId);
        return exits != null && exits.isDone();
    }

    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(String taskId, Runnable task, Date date) {

        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduled = scheduleMap.get(taskId);
        if (scheduled==null ) {
            ScheduledFuture<?> future = taskScheduler.schedule(task, date);
            scheduleMap.put(taskId, future);
            return future;
       
        } else {
         // log it is already scheduled
            return scheduled;
       }
    }
```

i know it is too late but i hope others can get benefit from it

The logic behind the implementation is whenever you are trying to schedule a task, you will have to add it to the map with the taskId as well, in this case it is better to find any task if exists in MAP or if needed remove it as well as checking if that task is done or not

Comment: It is always better to explain the logic and then show code.

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani the logic behind it, is whenever you are scheduling any task (runnable) it is better to put it in a map, so later on you can find it based on task id,  whenever you are adding it is needed to add runnable with task id, so it is more optimized and better organized to find it later on, what is in Scheduler

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what your scheduler does really. For instance, you can produce a file or update a field in a db or such thing that can be checked and the time interval (from now to last update) can be calculated. In your case, if the time interval of file creation or db updated is more than half an hour this means the job did stop. But notice that scheduled jobs are meant to last forever like love.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But my problem is how to automate the process of checking whether the db update has taken place?

Comment: either you'll poll and see if your job worked (another scheduled job) or the working job will send an event (like a jms message) when it is sucessfully complete but of course you'll need a system that will receive these events.